# Request : Analyse GC Offline using Tool

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

For some strong reason, I do **NOT** have access to our JVM based Web - App servers when running LIVE Production and only way is the task of ***Monitoring the Activity Offline Only***.

Hence I or Our-Moron-Team cannot Monitor the JVM based GC  for any irregular memory usage.

Hence I ask the Experts  is there any way by using JRE based Settings to setup during initial startup.

This settings have to constantly write to log file on hourly basis.

This Log file could be analyzed Offline using Tool Visual JVM and easily get to know the Reason of Crash / irregularity behavior by the charts provided.

Can some body help me with the JVM settings.

with regards
karthik

Comment: You don not provide any useful information about what you ask. What JRE/Java EE platform are you using?

Answer (score 1):

**Garbage Collection activity**

You will need to activate the GC logs using the following JVM options : `-Xloggc:/path/to/logfile/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps`.

Then you can use tools such as [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer) (free, open-source), [HPJmeter](https://h20392.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=HPJMETER) (free) or [JClarity Censum](http://www.jclarity.com/products/censum/) (commercial) to analyse the logfile afterwards.

**Thread Dumps**

You can use [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/plugins.html) using the TDA (Thread Dump Analyzer) plugin. [TDA](https://java.net/projects/tda) is also available as a standalone application if you want to visualize Thread Dumps afterwards.

**Heap Dumps**

You can use [jhat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html) (standard tool) of [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to visualize a memory dump.

**What about Memory Leaks**

If you have a long-running GC log, you can give it to Censum that will tell you if your application suffer from a memory leak. Once you have this first information, you can take some snapshot and analyze them using Eclipse MAT or NetBeans Profiler to find out which objects are leaking.

Comment: Hi Thx for the Quick Reply ,Are there any tools /plugins to use within Visual JVM to monitor offline gc.logs with the preferred settings, Also are there any settings for attaining Visual JVM based Thread-dumps ,application-snapshots,Heap-dumps .... Please share the same also...   with regards karthik